# XSLT: Display all elements containing a specific child element (and only those elements)

Tags: xslt

I'm transforming from XML to HTML, and I only want the paragraphs that contain a specific element to show up. How do I do this?

My XML looks something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<text>
<p>This paragraph contains the <bingo>information</bingo> I want</p>
<p>This paragraph doesn't.</p>
<p>This paragraph doesn't</p>
<p>This paragraph contains the <nest><bingo>information</bingo></nest> I want, too</p>
<p>This paragraph doesn't</p>
</text>
```

So I want to output HTML that only contains paragraphs like the first and fourth.

So far I've got this.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
        <body>
            <h1>Bingo</h1>
            <div id="results">
                <xsl:for-each select="/text/p">
                    <xsl:if test="//bingo">
                        <p>
                            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                        </p>
                    </xsl:if>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>
```

It is obviously wildly wrong. But I don't know how I ought to be thinking about it. I'd be very grateful for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to select `p` elements which have a descendant of `bingo`, then the expression you want is this:

```
 <xsl:for-each select="text/p[descendant::bingo]">
```

This can also be written as this...

```
 <xsl:for-each select="text/p[.//bingo]">
```

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
        <body>
            <h1>Bingo</h1>
            <div id="results">
                <xsl:for-each select="text/p[.//bingo]">
                    <p>
                        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                    </p>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1):

Do it with template rules, not with loops and conditionals:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
        <body>
            <h1>Bingo</h1>
            <div id="results">
                <xsl:apply-templates>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="p[.//bingo]">
  <p><xsl:value-of select="."/></p>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="p"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

> So I want to output HTML that only contains paragraphs like the first
>   and fourth

**Simply use this**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <html>
        <body>
            <h1>Bingo</h1>
            <div id="results">
                <xsl:copy-of select="p[.//bingo]"/>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```